# Do we have two "any pronouns"- one is plural and the other is singular?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

In [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/pronouns) dictionary the definition of a pronoun is as below:

> Pronouns are used in place of a noun that has already been mentioned or that is already known, often to avoid repeating the noun.

Thus, based on the frequent pronouns, i.e., she, her, ..., I conclude that ***any*** as a pronoun cannot be both plural and singular at the same time. With this regard, which one is correct in below imaginary conversation?

> A: I need some screws.
>
> B: Is there any in your pocket? **or** Are there any in your pocket?

---

If I am wrong, I will be happy to know your correction(s).

Comment: ***Any*** can be used with a singular *mass noun*, or pluralized *count noun*. Thus, *Are there any apples in this fruit basket?* (whole fruits) and *Is there any apple in this fruit cocktail?** (pieces of apple, *some* apple).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think ***Any*** in your examples are acting as a determiner not a pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "any" in this case is referring to the **screw*s***, a plural noun, so it is plural.

> Are there any (screws) in your pocket?

but if it refers to a singular uncountable/mass noun, it is singular:

> Is there any (milk/food/bread/whatever) left?

Off-topic: if you are asking for one screw (or heck, an amount of a countable noun) *in someone else's possession*, I'd usually use

> **Do you have** any screws in your pocket?

And when you refer to an **indefinite amount of countable things** in English, you usually say it with the plural of the things.

> Were there any survivors?
>
> Do you get good grades?
>
> I like laptops that are cheap but don't break easily.
>
> Moshing was banned because some obnoxious guests brought weapons inside.

Comment: Therefore, depending on the context, any can be both. It is interesting since I thought that pronouns can be either plural or singular, but not the both.

Comment: Yes, but if the original statement was *I need a screw*, one would rarely say *Is there any in your pocket?* but *Is there one in your pocket?*

Comment: @Cardinal *Milk, food, water* are all mass nouns. If we are asking about a count noun  we'd more likely ask *Is there one in your pocket?*, *Is there one on the floor?*

Comment: @AlanCarmack Many thanks. I was reviewing my grammar book and my notes, I came across with this question. I had known that ***any*** can also be used with countable singular nouns as a determiner, but in the case of being a pronoun, I was dubious. That is great.

Comment: @Nihilist => It seems I was not completely successful to from a good imaginary scenario. I mean, I didn't ask how to say "do you have something"!. I was asking about the grammars behind the ***any*** as a pronoun. BTW, It is cool

Comment: @Cardinal Note that I didn't say we can't use *any* as a pronoun for a countable singular noun. *I told him to call a friend; he said he didn't have any.* So, technically *Is there any in your pocket?* is okay, but not likely to be said. You could ask *Is there any question I haven't answered? Any at all?* So, yes *any* can be used to refer to either a singular or plural count noun.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I think "any" in your example: "any question" is a determiner not a pronoun. Am I wrong?

Comment: *Any*, as a determiner or as a pronoun,  can be used to refer to a  singular or plural count noun. It is a pronoun if the noun is omitted: *Is there any (man) who knows the answer?* and *Are there any (men) who know the answer?* But in your context, few people I know would ask *Is there any (screw) in your pocket?*